# How to effectively read thesis and research articles in molecular genetics/ systems biology?

Tags: research-process

I am new to research. My thesis supervisor gave me a few articles and a thesis to read. I started reading the thesis from the beginning to the end and I feel like I am going nowhere. My research topic is molecular genetics/ systems biology. Considering the fact that I only have a BSc degree in Physics, how should I read these? I feel like it will take me ages to finish just one article.

Comment: Don't get bogged down too much by all the small biological details, you can often understand much of the paper without getting stuck on these.

Comment: You have a supervisor... Ask your supervisor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you will receive lots of advice on how to read efficiently. Some of it will be useful for you, some won't - many of these tips will only really work when you know what you are looking for or are sufficiently familiar with the way things are presented in a particular field that you can see the important points immediately.

However, I would advise you, that as a new starter in the field, to a certain extent, you'll just need to accept that it is going to take you a long time.  I can now read a reasonably size paper in an average of an hour, but a paper could easily take me a day when I was where you are now (approx. the same field), and I had a biology degree. You will get quicker as you get more practiced, I promise.

When coming from a new field, the hardest thing will be deciding on how much of the background it is necessary to understand, particularly in relation to methods - you do not have to go away are read up on every method you come across, sometimes you can just accept that it is saying what the authors claim, with really having to understand the detailed reasons why. Other times it is important to know what is going on. Learning which is which will help you cut down on unnecessary googling of terms/methods etc.

Comment: Thanks Ian. I am trying my best.